# session.getAttribute not returning the correct value

Tags: java

In one of my application i've set one variable (String) in a session. The detail code is below in one of my servlet.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String val1 = "http://abc.gmail.com/pp/hello.do?supplierId=894";
session.setAttribute("val1", val1);
```

Now i retrieved the value of the session attribute in one jsp by the below code.

```
<%
String val1 = (String) session.getAttribute("val1");
System.out.println("The value is-->>"+val1);
%>
```

But it's printing only "http://abc.gmail.com/pp/hello.do?supplierId"

Could you please help me fixing this error. I'm expecting the o/p to be 
"http://abc.gmail.com/pp/hello.do?supplierId=894"

Thanks,
Sourav

Comment: can you check if any other calling to the session object changes its value? you can debug and trace your calls.

Comment: @Sourav Bag The first part of your code is from Servlet File.???

Comment: Every thing is Fine with this Code. I think the issue is the Value is Being Reset or Session is Being Closed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible reasons for this:

1. Somewhere else in the code, the value is overwritten
2. You stripped too much code when you posted the example.

To find out which is which, you can:

1. Add a `System.out.println()` right after `session.setAttribute()` to see the value that is actually put into the session.
2. Create a filter that prints the value before and after each request. This will help you narrow down where it is modified.
3. Set a breakpoint in the implementation of `session.setAttribute()`. Might not be feasible when thousands of attributes are set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with =

try following

1. convert string in base64, put it in session
2. get string from session , convert base64 to normal

I should work

Comment: -1 web containers don't arbitrarily modify string values saved in the session. There is no reason to encode the string value since it's never passed via HTTP.

Comment: Yes..It looks like the issue is with the =. Now i've added the following encoding in the jsp <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>. But i didn't test it yet. Will let you know once the testing is performed.

Comment: sure, Thank you for your response. I'll wait for your response